# I need to input a value, and extract information of an object

Tags: c#, random

I need to be able to input a random value, search through a list of objects in a class, and find the one with an ID that matches the random value. To make things more complicated, I also have to extract all information I can on that item.

I have the random input:

```
firstCard = Random.Range (1, 18);
```

Then I have the cards:

```
public class Card {
    public int CardID;
    public string element;
    public int value;
    public string color;

    public Card (int cardids, string elementals, int values, string coloring) {
        this.CardID = cardids;
        this.element = elementals;
        this.value = values;
        this.color = coloring;
    }
}

public class CardList : MonoBehaviour {
    public Card a = new Card(1, "Fire", 3, "Blue");
    //Other cards appear here.
}
```

So if the random number returns 1, I want it to retun "Fire", 3, and "Blue" because the CardID matches the random number. These two groups of code are in two different files, if that changes anything.

Comment: Why not use a collection for your Cards instead of an explicit class property for each one?

Answer (score 1):

*"search through a list of objects in a class,"* doesn't look like you're creating a list, but define each card as field/property.

You should create a real list of cards:

```
var cards = new List<Card>();

// add the cards...
cards.Add(new Card(1, "Fire", 3, "Blue"));    
cards.Add(new Card(2, "Water", 4, "Red"));
```

To search for a card:

```
var random = new Random(); // do this ones...

//   <snip>

// generate a random id
int cardId = random.Next(1, 18);

// search for it
// if it isn't found (none matched the id) it will return null
var foundCard = cards.FirstOrDefault(card => card.CardID == cardId);

// is it found?
if (foundCard != null)
{
    // card is found.
    MessageBox.Show($"The card is of element {foundCard.element}");
}
else
{
    // card is NOT found.
    MessageBox.Show("Too bad, the card is not found");
}
```

---

**Next chapter: *Dictionaries***

Comment: "The name 'cards' does not exist in the current context." And if I change it to 'Card', I get the error: "'Card' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault'."

Comment: Maybee I was a little too fast. You need to create a field for the `cards`. This way it is also accessable from other methods. You might read up at [Fields (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx). It will explain how to solve the error you had.